# Java : Serializable not working to save Object's states

Tags: java, object, serialization, file-io

i am trying simple program in `Java to save objects state using Serializable` through follwing code , once i writes these objects and then make them to null but `when i  try  to get them back it gives me null values`  ,should not it give me  the stored values ?  `when i run this program answer is null null null` , please see and  guide me  about it ,

Game.java

```
public class Game implements Serializable{

    public Game() {
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        Type = type;
    }

    public String[] getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String[] name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    int  size; 
    String Type ; 
    String [] name; 

    public   Game (int thesize , String theType, String[] names )
    {

        this.size = thesize; 
        this.Type= theType;
        this.name = names; 
    }

}
```

GameCharacter.java

```
public class GameCharacter extends Game {

    public GameCharacter(int i, String Type, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Game g= new Game();

        GameCharacter GC1= new GameCharacter(1, "One " , new  String [] {"bow", "SWord", "Dust"});
        GameCharacter GC2 = new GameCharacter(2, "TWo", new String[] {"One ", "TWo ", "Three"});
        GameCharacter GC3= new GameCharacter(3, "Three", new String[] {"four ", "five ", "six"}); 

        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream("Game.ser"));
        oos.writeObject(GC1);
        oos.writeObject(GC2);
        oos.writeObject(GC3);
        oos.close();          
        GC1= null;
        GC2= null; 
        GC3= null; 

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Game.ser"));

        try
        {
            GameCharacter onerestore= (GameCharacter) ois.readObject();
            GameCharacter tworestore  = (GameCharacter) ois.readObject();
            GameCharacter threerestore= (GameCharacter) ois.readObject();
            System.out.print(onerestore.getName());
            System.out.println(tworestore.getType());
            System.out.println(threerestore.getName());
            //System.out.println("HEllo");

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GameCharacter constructor doesn't call the constructor for Game, so you're passing in parameters that just get ignored.  Try running your println() statements on your original objects; you'll get the same nulls output.  Fix that and serialization will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is serializing the object, but the fields are all null. In your GameCharacter's constructor you need to call the correct super constructor, else by default the constructor called is the default constructor with no parameters.

```
 public GameCharacter(int i, String Type, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       super(i, Type, strings); //you do not have this, hence your variables are null.
    }
```

On a side note, Type is a java class, please do not use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

yes the class GameCharacter extends Game .and there is a constructor in the GameCharacter.
so  GameCharacter onerestore= (GameCharacter) ois.readObject() will call the constuctor defined in the sub class GameCharacter.
  but look at here

```
public GameCharacter(int i, String Type, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

yes this constructor do nothing at all.
so those field still null;
try to change the constuctor as follows ,you may succeed .

```
public GameCharacter(int i, String Type, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super( i ,Type,strings);
    }
```